# React-Router-Dom - redirecting doesn't cause re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm building an online library site and every book has its own page which is set on: /script/:id/
On the book page, I'm showing recommendations for similar books, and when the user clicks one of those, it should redirect him to the book page. Although, when I use useHistory and just push the route there, the URL changes, but the component itself does not rerender with new data.

Route:

```
<Route exact path="/script/:id">
    <ScriptsPage getScript={(e) => getScript(e)} />
</Route>
```

The component where I'm calling the redirection:

```
const ScriptCard = ({ title, author, year, image, id }) => {
    const [ width, setWidth ] = useState(window.innerWidth);
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => setWidth(window.innerWidth));
    
    const history = useHistory();

    function redirect() {
        history.push(`/script/${id}}`);
    }

    return (
        <div className="scriptcard" onClick={() => redirect()}>
            <div className="image">
                <img src={`${path}/${image}`} />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <h5 className="title">{title}</h5>
                <p className="text">{author}</p>
                <p className="text">{year}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

ScriptsPage

```
const ScriptsPage = ({ getScript = (f) => f }) => {
    const [ , setState ] = useState();
    const history = useHistory();
    const path = 'http://localhost:8000';
    const [ scriptInfo, setScriptInfo ] = useState();
    const id = useParams().id;

    useEffect(async () => {
        const response = await getScript(id);
        setScriptInfo(response.data.data);
    }, []);

    const redirectToViewer = () => {
        console.log('redirecting to viewer');
        history.push(`/viewer/${id}`);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {!scriptInfo ? (
                <h1>Loading</h1>
            ) : (
                <div className="scriptspage">
                    <div>
                        // I'm displaying data here, but it has nothing to do 
                           with the question
                    </div>
                    <div className="similar-scripts">
                        <ScriptsCarousel
                            title={`Viac z kategórie ${scriptInfo.category}`}
                            id={id}
                            tag={scriptInfo.category}
                            limit={10}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

EDIT: I'm aware that there is an option to use forceRefresh on router itself, but I'd rather solve it on component level rather than having page refreshing in browser on every page redirect.

Comment: Please add `ScriptsPage` code.

Comment: @JJJ hi, i edited the post

Comment: Where do you invoke < ScriptCard /> ?

Comment: There is an another component called ScriptCarousel, but it is basically just an container that holds 5 ScriptCards and adds some styling effects to it, nothing is really called there data-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `useEffect(() => {},[])` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) here. However, you must use `useState` and use your `useHistory()` state in your `useEffect`.

useEffect should force a re-render whenever you update your state after pushing:

```
export default ScriptCard = ({ title, author, year, image, id }) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [stateHistory, setStateHistory] = useState(useHistory()); // <--- here
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  window.addEventListener("resize", () => setWidth(window.innerWidth));
  let path = "test";

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Successfully pushed to ${stateHistory}!`);
  }, [stateHistory]); // <--- here

  const redir = (stateHistory) => {
    stateHistory.push(`/script/${id}`); // <--- here
    setStateHistory({ ...stateHistory }); // <--- here
  };

  return (
    <div className="scriptcard" onClick={() => redir(stateHistory)}> // <!-- here -->
      <div className="image">
        <img alt="test" src={`${path}/${image}`} />
      </div>
      <div className="content">
        <h5 className="title">{title}</h5>
        <p className="text">{author}</p>
        <p className="text">{year}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also add it to `ScriptsPage` too.

```
const ScriptsPage = ({ getScript = (f) => f }) => {
    const [ , setState ] = useState();
    const [stateHistory, setStateHistory] = useState(useHistory()); // <--- here
    const path = 'http://localhost:8000';
    const [ scriptInfo, setScriptInfo ] = useState();
    const id = useParams().id;

    useEffect(async () => {
        const response = await getScript(id);
        setScriptInfo(response.data.data);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`Successfully pushed to ${stateHistory}!`);
    }, [stateHistory]); // <--- here

    const redirectToViewer = (stateHistory) => {
        console.log('redirecting to viewer');
        stateHistory.push(`/viewer/${id}`); // <--- here
        setStateHistory({ ...stateHistory }); // <--- here
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {!scriptInfo ? (
                <h1>Loading</h1>
            ) : (
                <div className="scriptspage">
                    <div>
                        // I'm displaying data here, but it has nothing to do 
                           with the question
                    </div>
                    <div className="similar-scripts">
                        <ScriptsCarousel
                            title={`Viac z kategórie ${scriptInfo.category}`}
                            id={id}
                            tag={scriptInfo.category}
                            limit={10}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};
```

**I've also added a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-monad-88g2e?file=/src/App.js) to help demonstrate.**

Comment: It doesn't work, the console.log doesn't get triggered and the component doesn't rerender

Comment: Hey Michal, I think I fixed it, let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Add `history.go(0)` after your `history.push`

```
function redirect() {
    history.push(`/script/${id}}`);
    history.go(0)
}
```

Here is a codesandbox with differents usages of react-router, maybe it could help you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-with-redirect-forked-9jqjh?file=/src/root.js:460-478

Comment: Yeah, thanks that does technically work, because it refreshes the page ? Is there perhaps another way that would just rerender the component ? But thanks a lot, if I won't find any solution, I'll sure use this one, because it's better than having to refresh on every redirect.

Comment: could you replicate your error in codesandbox? I could help you better...